# Spotfire v7.5 : Edit Existing Data table join

Tags: join, spotfire

In Spotfire, I have inserted columns From an Excel File in an existing Data Table on Spotfire (See example shows at the End) but I have made a mistake in the join property. Could I change it without re creating the complete Data Table or using calculated columns/Filters?

Comment: The examples mentioned are missing...

Answer (score 0):

You can only edit it by deleting the inserted columns and adding them again.

Comment: Even if we remove the inserted columns the JOIN is still present between the tables.  Could you please guide me here?

Comment: Sorry, I am afraid I won't be able to help. It has been 5 years since I have touched Spotfire.